# Making Collection View section cells move horizontally while sections are placed vertically over each other

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I want to make a collection view which has say 'n' number of sections. The cells for each section should scroll horizontally while the sections are placed vertically. Something like:-

- Section 1

  cell1,cell2,cell3,cell4 and so on.
- Section 2

  cell1,cell2,cell3,cell4 and so on.
- Section n

  cell1,cell2,cell3,cell4 and so on.

Comment: Use a table view. In each custom table view row, use collection view

Comment: Thanks.........That solved my problem. :)